# Calculating missing months

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I use the following query in ordre to filling missing months

```
Declare @Sample Table(year int, month int,product as nvarchar(50), qty_ytd int);
Insert @Sample(year, month, qty_ytd) Values
(2017,   01,'book',    20),
(2017,   02, 'pc',   30),
(2018,   01, 'book',    50);

;With Months As
(Select 1 As month
Union All
Select month + 1 From Months Where month < 12)
, YearsAndMonths As
(Select distinct year,m.month from @Sample cross join Months m)

select ym.*, coalesce(s.qty_ytd, s2.qty_ytd) qty_ytd, coalesce(s.qty_ytd, 0) QTY from YearsAndMonths ym
left join @sample s on ym.year = s.year and ym.month = s.month
left join (select qty_ytd, year,
                  row_number() over (partition by year order by month desc) rn
           from @Sample) s2 on ym.year = s2.year and rn = 1
```

How could I add 'product ' as well ?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing expected results.

Comment: `cross join` with `distinct product`

Comment: use `year, product` every time when you're using `year`

Comment: Have you tested the sample? it will not compile.

Comment: @csharp . . . Your code does not run.  Please show the results that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows that you want -- all the years, months, and products.

Then use `left join` to bring in the data you want:

```
With Months As (
      Select 1 As month
      Union All
      Select month + 1
      From Months
      Where month < 12
     )
select y.year, m.month, s.product, coalesce(qty_ytd, 0) as qty_ytd
from (select distinct year from @sample) y cross join
     months m cross join
     (select distinct product from @sample) p left join
     @sample s
     on s.year = y.year and s.month = m.month and s.product = p.product;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4df77c9cda5a4e1f1cd53ad258de49c1) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would recommend creating a calendar table since this pops up as a use case every once in a while. A quick example can be found [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

Now, once you have the calendar table (let's call it static.calendar) ready, the code is fairly simple as follows:

```
with Products
as
(
    SELECT distinct product
    FROM @Sample
),
TimeRange
as
(
    SELECT DISTINCT year,
        month
    FROM static.calendar
)
ProductTimeRange
as
(
    SELECT p.products,
        tr.year,
        tr.month
    FROM Products as p
    CROSS JOIN TimeRange as tr
)
SELECT ptr.products,
    ptr.year,
    ptr.month,
    s.qty_ytd
FROM ProductTimeRange as ptr
LEFT JOIN @sample as s
    ON ptr.products = s.products
    AND ptr.year = s.year
    AND ptr.month = s.month
ORDER BY ptr.products,
    ptr.year,
    ptr.month
```

---